# Iterating objects inside an array

Tags: reactjs

How do I get `"name"` from objects instead of `{item}`?

```
class Abc extends Component {
    state = {
        tags: [
            {
                "id": 1
                "name": "goal"
            },
            {
                "id": 2
                "name": "kick"
            }
        ]
    }

    render() {
        return (
            .................................
            <div>
                {this.state.tags.map((item, index) => (
                    <span key={index}>{item}</span>
                ))}
            </div>
            ...................................
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just access it directly.

```
class Abc extends Component {
    state = {
        tags: [
            {
                "id": 1
                "name": "goal"
            },
            {
                "id": 2
                "name": "kick"
            }
        ]
    }

    render() {
        return (
            .................................
            <div>
                {this.state.tags.map((item, index) => (
                    <span key={item.id}>{item.name}</span>
                ))}
            </div>
            ...................................
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You should also use the object's `id` property as the key, rather than the index (assuming the `id` property is unique)

Comment: Edited to implement suggestion from @Jayce444